# Xubuntu 16.04 - Set background image for all users (system wide)

Tags: xfce, system, desktop-background

I'm trying to set a system wide background image for all users on xubungu 16.04.
Xubuntu version:

```
dpkg -l xubuntu-desktop
Gewünscht=Unbekannt/Installieren/R=Entfernen/P=Vollständig Löschen/Halten
| Status=Nicht/Installiert/Config/U=Entpackt/halb konFiguriert/
         Halb installiert/Trigger erWartet/Trigger anhängig
|/ Fehler?=(kein)/R=Neuinstallation notwendig (Status, Fehler: GROSS=schlecht)
||/ Name                                          Version                     Architektur                 Beschreibung
+++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-===============================
ii  xubuntu-desktop                               2.206                       i386                        Xubuntu desktop system
```

The started session is

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4
```

I know, that user-related settings are held in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml`

I tried to bring in settings under `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml`, but they don't take effekt.

If I logout, delete the whole `~/.config/xfce4` folder and login again, the user-related settings are written again.

These are the user-related defaults, that are currently written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel name="xfce4-desktop" version="1.0">
  <property name="backdrop" type="empty">
    <property name="screen0" type="empty">
      <property name="monitor0" type="empty">
        <property name="workspace0" type="empty">
          <property name="color-style" type="int" value="0"/>
          <property name="image-style" type="int" value="5"/>
          <property name="last-image" type="string" value="/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-teal.jpg"/>
        </property>
        <property name="workspace1" type="empty">
          <property name="color-style" type="int" value="0"/>
          <property name="image-style" type="int" value="5"/>
          <property name="last-image" type="string" value="/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-teal.jpg"/>
        </property>
        <property name="workspace2" type="empty">
          <property name="color-style" type="int" value="0"/>
          <property name="image-style" type="int" value="5"/>
          <property name="last-image" type="string" value="/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-teal.jpg"/>
        </property>
        <property name="workspace3" type="empty">
          <property name="color-style" type="int" value="0"/>
          <property name="image-style" type="int" value="5"/>
          <property name="last-image" type="string" value="/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-teal.jpg"/>
        </property>
      </property>
    </property>
  </property>
</channel>
```

This is the line, that holds the correct setting in my opinion:

```
<property name="last-image" type="string" value="/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-teal.jpg"/>
```

So thats how I tried to set it under `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- default settings -->
<channel name="xfce4-desktop" version="1.0">
  <property name="desktop-icons" type="empty">
    <property name="style" type="int" value="2"/>
    <property name="file-icons" type="empty">
      <property name="show-home" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <property name="show-filesystem" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <property name="show-removable" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <property name="show-trash" type="bool" value="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon-size" type="uint" value="48"/>
    <property name="tooltip-size" type="double" value="64.000000"/>
  </property>
  <property name="backdrop" type="empty">
    <property name="screen0" type="empty">
      <property name="monitor0" type="empty">
        <property name="image-path" type="string" value="/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-wallpaper.png"/>
        <property name="image-style" type="int" value="5"/>
        <property name="image-show" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <property name="workspace0" type="empty">
           <property name="last-image" type="string" value="/usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/Terraform-green.jpg"/>
        </property>
      </property>
      <property name="monitor1" type="empty">
        <property name="image-path" type="string" value="/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-wallpaper.png"/>
        <property name="image-style" type="int" value="5"/>
        <property name="image-show" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </property>
    </property>
  </property>
</channel>
```

The following search only returns my own attempt to set the global background:

```
find /etc -type f -exec grep last-image {} /dev/null \; 2> /dev/null
/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml:           <property name="last-image" type="string" value="/usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/Terraform-green.jpg"/>
```

The thread, that led me to the files under `/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu`:

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6999

**UPDATE:**

I noticed, that my settings take effekt, if I make the following adjustments:

```
cp /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/
```

Note: the `xfce4-desktop.xml` file didn't exist in the target directory.

This fact and [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055912) led me to the Variable `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`

```
echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
/etc/xdg/xdg-default:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
```

Note: I use gdm3 as session manager, and have set the system default to `startxfce4` (as noticed previously). I have done that, becasuse `startxfce4` is the binary used in `/usr/share/xsessions/xubuntu.desktop`

If I select directly xubuntu-Session (not system default!), the variable `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` is set as follows:

```
echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
```

I want to use the system default, so what I try now is

```
ln -sf /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu /etc/xdg/xdg-default
```

Keep you up to date if it worked.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My problems probably came from the use of gdm3.

As pointed out [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055912), the value of the variable XDG_CONFIG_DIRS depends on the used .desktop file under /usr/share/xsessions.

So to place a global configuration it is crucial, that the configuration is read (logical..) and the configuration is read when it is placed in one of the paths named in XDG_CONFIG_DIRS.

**Solution:**

1. place configuration (e.g. desktop background) under `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml`
   for the desktop-background the necessary line is

Set the value to the path of the desired image
The whole configuration file fo rme looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- default settings -->
<channel name="xfce4-desktop" version="1.0">
  <property name="desktop-icons" type="empty">
    <property name="style" type="int" value="2"/>
    <property name="file-icons" type="empty">
      <property name="show-home" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <property name="show-filesystem" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <property name="show-removable" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <property name="show-trash" type="bool" value="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon-size" type="uint" value="48"/>
    <property name="tooltip-size" type="double" value="64.000000"/>
  </property>
  <property name="backdrop" type="empty">
    <property name="screen0" type="empty">
      <property name="monitor0" type="empty">
        <property name="image-path" type="string" value="/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-wallpaper.png"/>
        <property name="image-style" type="int" value="5"/>
        <property name="image-show" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <property name="workspace0" type="empty">
           <property name="last-image" type="string" value="/usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/Terraform-green.jpg"/>
        </property>
      </property>
      <property name="monitor1" type="empty">
        <property name="image-path" type="string" value="/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-wallpaper.png"/>
        <property name="image-style" type="int" value="5"/>
        <property name="image-show" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </property>
    </property>
  </property>
</channel>
```

2. Link the path where your configuration was made (`/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu`) to the path `/etc/xdg/xdg-default`, in order to make it take effekt, if you chose "system default" in gdm3

   `ln -sf /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu /etc/xdg/xdg-default`
3. If you haven't made your settings mandatory (add an `unlocked="root"` to the property, (looks like that:

Source: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6999), then make sure user settings don't override them.
You could log out and do

```
rm ~/.config/xfce4
```

4. Login again

Correct me if anything can be done better.